# Remove ssh greeter message

Tags: ssh

I'd like to remove the ssh greeter message because that messes up some protocols.

I've tried many things, all with no avail:

- removed the motd in /etc/pam.d/sshd
- Banner /dev/null in /etc/ssh/sshd_config
- chmod -x /etc/update-motd.d/*
- Create empty touch ~/.hushlogin

After all of this, it still says `elementary OS Loki`. How can I remove that message?

Answer (score 1):

If the message messes the protocol, it is not MotD nor `Banner`, but it is written from some of the startup scripts. You should check for `~/.bashrc` or other scripts used by your shell.

Consult your shell manual page to see what scripts are being used at startup, grep over the `/etc/` where this string is written.

Comment: So I suspect is the cause for the protocol mess up, but until I fix it I can't be sure. Secondly, I suspect that this is not a hard-coded string but rather printing out the current version hold in some variable...

Comment: You can simply test if `scp` works. If it does, it *should* not break any other protocol. Does it show before login or after? It might also come from PAM stack.

Comment: Unfortunately I am now at my office computer without my laptop to check whether `scp` is working or not. PAM I thought I removed (as per my first bullet point).

Comment: Well, there might be some includes from other pam stacks and it can be written from other pam modules than motd. Yes, and I meant the `scp` to that machine.